# Issues with response from express file to front end (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am making a basic questionnaire within a react full stack website I am creating using React, Express and SQL.

At the moment all I am trying to do is return a error message from react and get my front end to display it .

This is my express endpoint.

```
app.post("/post-question-answers", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("!called");
  try {
    await sql.connect(config);

    // create Request object

    let selectedWorkstation = req.body.selectedWorkstation;

    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.input(`SelectedWorkstation`, sql.NVarChar, selectedWorkstation);
    let existingWSA = await request.execute("dbo.CheckIfWSAExists");
    if (!existingWSA.recordset.length) {
      console.info("hello from first if");
      let user = req.body.user;
      let results = req.body.results;
      let completeToken = req.body.completeToken;
      let date = req.body.date;

      let questions = [];
      let answers = [];
      // let emails = [];
      let questionIds = [];
      let suggestedSolutions = [];

      results.forEach(element => answers.push(element.answer));
      results.forEach(element => questions.push(element.question));
      // results.forEach(element => emails.push(element.email));
      results.forEach(element => questionIds.push(element.questionId));
      results.forEach(element =>
        suggestedSolutions.push(element.suggestedSolution)
      );

      var request = new sql.Request();
      request.input(`QuestionStatus`, sql.NVarChar, completeToken);
      request.input(`Date`, sql.NVarChar, date);
      request.input(`Email`, sql.NVarChar, user);
      request.input(`SelectedWorkstation`, sql.NVarChar, selectedWorkstation);
      let result = await request.execute("dbo.AddQuestionResponseHeader");

      console.log("HERE");
      console.log(result);
      if (result.hasOwnProperty("recordset") && result.recordset.length) {
        var recordsetRow = result.recordset[0];

        if (recordsetRow.hasOwnProperty("createdId")) {
          var id = recordsetRow.createdId;
          console.log(id);

          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var request = new sql.Request();
            let answer = answers[i];
            let question = questions[i];
            // let email = emails[i];
            let questionId = questionIds[i];
            let solution = suggestedSolutions[i];

            request.input(`WSAId`, sql.Int, id);
            request.input(`Question`, sql.NVarChar, question);
            request.input(`Answer`, sql.NVarChar, answer);
            request.input(`Email`, sql.NVarChar, user);
            request.input(`QuestionId`, sql.NVarChar, questionId);
            // request.input(`CompleteToken`, sql.NVarChar, completeToken);
            request.input(
              `SelectedWorkstation`,
              sql.NVarChar,
              selectedWorkstation
            );
            request.input(`SuggestedSolution`, sql.NVarChar, solution);

            request.execute("dbo.SubmitQuestionResponses", function(
              err,
              recordset
            ) {
              if (err) console.log(err);
            });
          }
        } else {
          console.log("unexpected result format");
        }
      } else {
        console.log("No results found");
      }
    } else {
// HERE is what I am asking about
      console.info("This account exists");
      let errorMessage =
        "This Workstation currently has an assessment in progress";
      res.status(409).json({
        errorMessage: errorMessage
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

So this is working fine the response is within the final else is (where the comment is).This is reached when a workstation exists and works fine.I then try to pass back this error message within this else.

This is my fetch statement within my submit answers function

```
 submitAnswers() {
    let selectedWorkstation = window.localStorage.getItem("Workstation");
    let user = window.localStorage.getItem("User");

    let completeToken = "";
    let declinedCounter = 0;

    if (questionCounter == this.state.questions.length) {
      var today = new Date(),
        date = `${today.getUTCFullYear()}-${today.getUTCMonth() +
          1}-${today.getUTCDate()} ${today.getHours()}:${today.getMinutes()}:${today.getSeconds()}.${today.getMilliseconds()} `;

      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        if (results[i].answer == "P") {
          declinedCounter++;
        } else {
        }
      }

      if (declinedCounter > 0) {
        completeToken = "In Progress";
      } else if (declinedCounter <= 0) {
        completeToken = "Complete";
      }

      console.log(completeToken);
      const data = {
        completeToken,
        results,
        selectedWorkstation,
        date,
        user: user
      };

      fetch("/post-question-answers/", {
        method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json,",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }).then(({ errorMessage }) => {
        this.setState({ errorMessage: errorMessage });
        alert(this.setState.errorMessage);
        

// Here is what I am referencing

        if (this.setState.errorMessage.length > 2) {
          alert("test1");
        } else if (this.setState.errorMessage.length < 2) {
          alert("test2");
        }
      });

      window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/completed-assessment";
    } else {
      alert("Please enter all of The questions");
    }
  }
```

This error message has worked once or twice on first use. Then it is either undefined or does not alert the user anything.

I am searching for the reason that this is not displayed every time a workstation exists. As it is usually undefined or will not show at all.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What will be alerted when you do: `this.setState({ errorMessage: errorMessage });
        alert(errorMessage);`? Looks like errorMessage can be undefined so `this.state.errorMessage.length` can cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrectly accessing the state variables. State variables are accessed using `this.state` not `this.setState`.

Also, put the alert in the callback of setState. setState is asynchronous, so by the time you use `this.state.errorMessage` inside alert, it may have not been updated yet. So, instead try this:

```
this.setState({errorMessage}, () => {alert(this.state.errorMessage)})
```

Comment: This has been changed to no avail. That was just a small typo but the alert does not work either where error message is pulled straight from the .then.This also should be displaying the error message.

Comment: @henrypf I have edited my answer. Hope it will solve your problem.